# KDEconnect - обзор устройства открывает пустую папку

Tags: android, linux

На моем компьютере установлена Debian Testing cо средой Cinnamon.

Я соединил компьютер и телефон на Android 8 через KDEconnect. При нажатии на "Обзор устройства" запускается Nemo в котором открывается папка `/home/kraamis/.cache/kioexec/krun/63952_0` c файлом под названием `unnamed` нулевого размера. Все разрешения на телефоне даны, все остальные функции KDEconnect работают нормально.

Что делать?

Comment: Папки добавленны в модуль просмотр папок на телефоне?

Comment: Конечно. Все по инструкции.

Comment: Gvfs-fuse gvfs-bin стоят?

Comment: Да. Стоят, последние версии.